# Unable to set keybinding with the down arrow key in emacs

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following keybindings for jumping 10 lines.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-up>") (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 10)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-down>") (lambda () (interactive) (next-line 10)))
```

The problem is that the C-up binding works and the cursor jumps 10 lines back, but nothing happens on C-down. What might be the reason?

Comment: It works for me. What do you get for `C-h k C-down`?

Comment: It may be overridden by another keymap (e.g. if the current local map,  which overrides the global map, binds it to something else).